# Rules for 2-tier recursive syntaxes

Tags: syntax-highlighting, delimiter-matching

I have matched parentheses, but highlighting failed as it transcends up the recursion stack.

[image: Example named.conf simplified syntax]

I just need to know if there is a solution to tracking pairs of delimiters during Vim highlight syntax of nested curly braces.

## Details

Was adapting [ISC Bind9](https://github.com/isc-projects/bind9) named configuration file using [their documentation](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-01493) full of BNF syntax into Vim syntax.

One is the `address_match_list` whose BNF is:

```
address_match_list :=  ( name | number | address_match_list ) ;
```

It's easy to make that Vim syntax for above BNF for 1st time.

Now, the actual usage of `address_match_list` in a recursive manner, it lost the tracking of closing curly braces and no longer highlights on the way back up the recursion stack (if there is any).

```
syn match xyz_Semicolon contained /;/ skipwhite skipempty
\ containedin=xyz_AML

syn match xyz_Number contained "\<\d\{1,10}\>" skipwhite skipempty
\ nextgroup=xyz_Semicolon
\ containedin=xyz_AML

" { ... }  ;
syn region xyz_AML contained start=+{+ end=+}+ skipwhite skipempty
\ nextgroup=
\    xyz_Number,
\    xyz_Semicolon

" <acl_name> ( <number> | { ... } ) ;
syn match xyz_ACLIdent contained /\<[0-9a-zA-Z\-_]\{1,63}\>/ skipwhite
\ nextgroup=
\    xyz_AML,
\    xyz_Number

syn match xyz_Keywords /\_^\s*\<acl\>/ skipempty skipwhite
\ nextgroup=xyz_ACLIdent
```

For the condensed (but working) config file:

```
acl e 127;
acl internal-net {
    127; 10; 192;
};
acl an_internal_vps_ntwk {
    192;
    {
        172;
        {
            5;
        };
        6;
    };
    112;
};
```

All files can be found in PasteBin

- [syntax/mytest.vim](https://pastebin.com/rQqw58Eh)
- [ftdetect/mytest.vim](https://pastebin.com/Kn6euVgn)
- [example-mytest.conf](https://pastebin.com/35sa1C8y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the syn-extend and the use of [`keepend` and `extend`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn-extend) keywords, I used `Error` for my first region syntax and `Todo` for that last character after the region (semicolon). My recursive `region` is foreground white-colored.

With a bit of a bit of trial and error, got it to work:

[image: Working 2-tiered recursion of Vim syntaxes]

Then started to pare-down all non-essential keywords until it just works.

```
syn match xyz_Semicolon contained /;/

syn match xyz_AML_Nested_Semicolon contained /;/ skipwhite skipempty
\ nextgroup=
\    xyz_AML_Placeholder

syn match xyz_Number "\<\d\{1,10}\>" skipwhite skipempty
\ nextgroup=
\    xyz_AML_Nested_Semicolon

syn region xyz_AML_Placeholder contained start=+{+ end=+}+ keepend extend
\ contains=
\    xyz_Number,
\    xyz_AML_Nested_Semicolon
\ nextgroup=
\    xyz_AML_Nested_Semicolon

" acl <acl_name> { ... } ;
syn region xyz_AML contained start=+{+ end=+}+  skipwhite skipempty
\ contains=
\    xyz_Number,
\    xyz_AML_Nested_Semicolon
\ nextgroup=
\    xyz_Semicolon

" acl <acl_name> { ... } 
syn match xyz_ACLIdent contained /\<[0-9a-zA-Z\-_]\{1,63}\>/ skipwhite skipempty
\ nextgroup=
\    xyz_AML

" acl <acl_name> ...
syn match xyz_Keywords /acl/ skipwhite skipempty
\ nextgroup=xyz_ACLIdent

syn match xyz_Keywords /test/ skipwhite skipempty
\ nextgroup=xyz_Number
```

## Analysis:

The key thing during your Vim syntax debugging effort (other than the constant reloading) is to make use of:

- `Error` highlight to color your `region` as red and
- a bright color (`Todo`) for its last character after the region (semicolon).

While you debug (or randomly try) new syntax, and you get that last character to stay properly colorized as `xyz_Semicolon`, you will then be able to rock the rest of the syntaxes until you're happy, knowingly that you preserved your multiple nesting (recursive syntax).

In my case, I had two cases of near-duplication of the same `region` syntax.  Most of you wouldn't be facing this (unless you're a NeoVim or a Python Vim syntax maintainer).  Reason is I need two similar `region` syntaxes, is to perform a "tee-off" of limited capability before going into full-recursion syntax.

Full recursion is the following BNF:

```
address_match_list :== ( number | address_match_list ) ;
```

I had to wrap the `address_match_list` with:

```
acl_keyword :== 'acl'
acl_identifier :== [a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]{1,63}
acl_AML :== '{' + address_match_list + '}' + ';'
```

Working test files are:

- [test named.conf file](https://pastebin.com/bFqaYu3m)
- [working syntax/mytest.vim file](https://pastebin.com/4thVn4f1)

Comment: Also posted it on Github as well.  https://github.com/egberts/vim-2-tiered-recursion-syntax